# Adding three months to a date in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a variable called `$effectiveDate` containing the date **2012-03-26**.

I am trying to add three months to this date and have been unsuccessful at it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($effectiveDate));
```

and

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($effectiveDate)) . "+3 months");
```

What am I doing wrong? Neither piece of code worked.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: I'm getting `1340649000` as answer, which seems to be correct.

Comment: Are you sure `$effectiveDate` stores what you think it stores? [It works for me](http://codepad.org/nfHa8Oxx).

Comment: I am expecting that date to 2012-06-26 adding 3 months to 2012-03-26

Comment: And `date('Y-m-d', 1340661600)` gives `2012-06-26` which IS correct.

Comment: @user1193385 Read up on PHP's `strtotime`. `The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.`

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Change it to this will give you the expected format:

```
$effectiveDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($effectiveDate)));
```

Comment: How to deal with an variable of months? like $months contains the number of months? `"+ '$months' months"` does not work

Comment: `$offset = 5; echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$offset months", strtotime('2000-01-01')));` [Demo](http://ideone.com/H8k7lt)

Comment: date() don't use localizations. Better is strftime().

Comment: That wont work for dates like this: date('2018-01-31', strtotime('+ 3 month')). If the date ends in 31 and the next 3 months doesn't, it will not return the correct date.

Comment: not good solution - does not return correct values - as Dan H mentioned

Answer (score 38):

This answer is not exactly to this question. But I will add this since this question still searchable for how to add/deduct period from date.

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('+3 month'); // or you can use '-90 day' for deduct
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume by "didn't work" you mean that it's giving you a timestamp instead of the formatted date, because you were doing it correctly:

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($effectiveDate)); // returns timestamp
echo date('Y-m-d',$effectiveDate); // formatted version
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the date into a readable value. You may use strftime() or date().

Try this:

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($effectiveDate));
$effectiveDate = strftime ( '%Y-%m-%d' , $effectiveDate );
echo $effectiveDate;
```

This should work. I like using strftime better as it can be used for localization you might want to try it.

Answer (score 3):

[Tchoupi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229260/tchoupi) answer can be made a tad less verbose by concatenating the argument for strtotime() as follows:

```
$effectiveDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($effectiveDate . "+3 months") );
```

(This relies on magic implementation details, but you can always go have a look at them if you're rightly mistrustful.)

Answer (score 3):

The following should work,Please Try this:

```
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+1 months", strtotime(date("y-m-d")));
echo $time = date("y/m/d", $effectiveDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Following should work

```
$d = strtotime("+1 months",strtotime("2015-05-25"));
echo   date("Y-m-d",$d); // This will print **2015-06-25**
```

Answer (score 1):

Add nth Days, months and years

```
$n = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++){
    $d = strtotime("$i days");
    $x = strtotime("$i month");
    $y = strtotime("$i year");
    echo "Dates : ".$dates = date('d M Y', "+$d days");
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Months : ".$months = date('M Y', "+$x months");
    echo '<br>';
    echo "Years : ".$years = date('Y', "+$y years");
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.3, `DateTime` along with `DateInterval` could be a feasible option to achieve the desired result.

```
$months = 6; 

$currentDate = new DateTime();

$newDate = $currentDate->add(new DateInterval('P'.$months.'M'));

echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you want to subtract time from a date, instead of `add`, use `sub`.

Here are more examples on how to use `DateInterval`:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');

// This creates an interval of 1 year, 2 months, 3 days, 4 hours, 5 minutes, and 6 seconds.

$interval = new DateInterval('P2W');

// This creates an interval of 2 weeks (which is equivalent to 14 days).

$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H30M');

// This creates an interval of 1 hour and 30 minutes (but no days or years, etc.).
```

Comment: I always forget the `P` in `DateInterval`, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, but you may need to change the format:

```
echo date('l F jS, Y (m-d-Y)', strtotime('+3 months', strtotime($DateToAdjust)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCurrentDate(){
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

public function getNextDateAfterMonth($date1,$monthNumber){
   return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+".$monthNumber." months", strtotime($date1))); 
}
```