# How To Add 10 Months To A Date

Tags: php, html

I've currently got a cut of PHP code that shows the date a user's account was created:

```
$user['contract_start']
```

For example, if I were to make a new account today and put that on a page while the account was logged in, it would come out with

```
2014-07-30
```

How can I alter this so that the code displays a string that adds exactly 10 months to the start date?

Comment: -1: Where is the $user object coming from? $user['contract_start'] is of what type? Fails basic debugging steps before asking question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding three months to a date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875076/adding-three-months-to-a-date-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

try this -

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 10 MONTHS', strtotime($date)))
```

Comment: `Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`. Should be `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 10 MONTH',strtotime($date)))`. see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9875196/689579

Comment: @sgt Congratulation's to 3k rep :D (Have fun to review all tasks)

Answer (score 2):

Using php [`Datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [`Datetime::add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$user['contract_start'] = '2014-07-30';
$date = new DateTime($user['contract_start']);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```