# Codeigniter add number to date

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have a number and I want to increase the month of date so if the date is `2016-01-01` will return `2016-04-01`

```
$month = 3;
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('date'))));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding three months to a date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875076/adding-three-months-to-a-date-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, But you could do something like:

```
$month = 3;
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$month." months", str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('date'))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add three months in a given date by using this:

```
$Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $this->input->post('date') ))));
```